# Как программно изменить порядок столбцов в Sharepoint content type?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Имеется ввиду изменение порядка столбцов в формах Создания и Редактирования элементов Sharepoint List используя либо Sharepoint 2010 Client Object Model либо Sharepoint 2010 Web Services.

Answer (score 2):

Поменять порядок отображения полей на формах можно программно или через веб-интерфейс в случаях, если для отображения используется веб-часть ListFormWebPart.
Напомню, что в формах по умолчанию, за генерацию полей отвечает ListFormWebPart. Но если Вы создаете новую форму, то функцию генерации html полей на себя берет DataFormWebPart. При этом каждое отдельное поле генерируется элементом управления FormField. Кастомизировать форму становиться намного легче, в случае использования DataFormWebPart, но если вы добавите новое поле, то добавлять его на форму придется самостоятельно, используя элемент FormField. Так же при использовании DataFormWebPart настройки порядка отображения полей не отражаются на форме.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell почти всегда удобнее в решении подобных вопросов, особенно если есть доступ на сервер. 
[Вот рабочий пример](http://johanolivier.blogspot.ru/2013/02/get-set-field-order-for-sharepoint-2010.html)